# Custom view loses background resource when not in view

Tags: android

So, I'm adding an ad from either AdMob or MMAds, **OR** I have the MMAds Interstitial ad come up, and on exit, **OR** I touch one of the list items, starting a new activity, then at the end of the activity, this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs2o3.png

The top item doesn't have a background resource being drawn, the bottom is similar to this.  This happens sometimes to the ones in the middle (With the ads, they ALL go away).

I was wondering why this happens and how to prevent it... The most I could find on other questions is one on using the following code on the ListView:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Or

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

The background resource is being drawin in the custom ListAdapter's getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method.

Any help is appreciated,

Justin W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had a bit of code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griddler_menu_choice_item, parent, false);
    } else {

        item = convertView;
    }
            return item;

}
```

Basically this was to keep it more efficient so it didn't have to keep creating Views as it's costly, but this somehow effected the end result... So now it works =).

Forgot to add in how to fix this... remove the else part and the if in general, just leave the line of code:

```
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.griddler_menu_choice_item, parent, false);
```

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

To verify your problem try to run `hierarchyviewer`, analize your views tree and try to find potential solution. Have you used Hierarchy Viewer?

Comment: I'll start looking into it now.

Comment: Ok, waiting for your response.

Comment: So, I checked two of the different List Views, and they match exactly except some of the x/y positions and mprivatemembers.  All the draw stuff is the same, along with everything else...  I checked this for the Relative Layout, Frame Layout, and other Relative Layout.  Is their anything I should look for specifically?

Comment: So maybe you can set your activity background with [getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))?
It will change the DecorView's background drawable (you can set the color of your choice as well).

Comment: I have a ListView with items in it.  Each item should be red, green, or yellow, depending on a status variable.  When these views are created and added to the Adapter, they're given a type, red, green, or yellow.  Now, as shown in the screenshot, it does work...  However, sometimes, and often, the Views in the ListView lose their custom drawable background.  It disapears when another Activity is opened, when it is not the visible in the layout, or other things...  Calling the command you suggested doesn't do much, I did it but things still lose their color/background. [cont].

Comment: I found that when I scroll the list view very quickly up and down, the Views lose their colors easily...  So, I also know that getView(int, View, ViewGroup) is called when this happens, however, their is no way for the new View returned returns a View that doesn't have the background applied...

Comment: I figured it out... I watched a video on a Google talk on optimization for Views, so I created a lil converting method, which used the second View argument to not have to re-create the item...  This actually solved the problem perfectly.  Thanks for the help, you did show that it had to be my error. Also, that HierarchyViewer is pretty neat =).

Comment: Good idea  @mmBs for helping people find more debugging tools.